# error in compiling a program in game maker studio

Tags: game-maker

I use game maker version 2.2.5.481 on windows 10. I am new to game maker studio. I want to compile a program and I face with the Compile Errors:

> Error : Build Failed

and my log file is:

```
option_android_version = { "build" : "0","major" : "1","minor" : "0","revision" : "0" }
usesShaders = False
Deleting armeabi
Deleting x86
Deleting x86_64
Deleting arm64
Deleting mips
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "subst W: "Z:/needle_FBFA8E44\Android\default" && W: && cd \com.company.game && "X://android/runner\gradle\gradlew" build  assembleRelease  -x lint  "

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not set process working directory to 'W:\com.company.game': could not set current directory (errno 3)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe DONE (1)
C:\Windows\system32\subst.exe /d W:


C:\Windows\system32\subst.exe DONE (0)
Error : Build Failed
Igor complete.
elapsed time 00:00:20.1591788s for command "C:\ProgramData/GameMakerStudio2/Cache/runtimes\runtime-2.2.5.378/bin/Igor.exe" -j=8 -options="C:\Users\masoo\AppData\Local\GameMakerStudio2\GMS2TEMP\build.bff" -v -- Android Package started at 09/02/2020 22:18:57
"cmd"  /c subst Z: /d

elapsed time 00:00:00.0550006s for command "cmd" /c subst Z: /d started at 09/02/2020 22:19:17
"cmd"  /c subst Y: /d

elapsed time 00:00:00.0463257s for command "cmd" /c subst Y: /d started at 09/02/2020 22:19:17
"cmd"  /c subst X: /d

elapsed time 00:00:00.0485943s for command "cmd" /c subst X: /d started at 09/02/2020 22:19:17
FAILED: Package Program Complete
For the details of why this build failed, please review the whole log above and also see your Compile Errors window.
```

I have googled alot and I couldn't find any solution, So how can I solve this problem.

Thanks all.

Comment: You can try googling the line `could not set process working directory to could not set current directory (errno 3)`, I think several have faced this problem before.

Comment: I googled it but unfortunately I couldn't find any solution